# R dplyr group by column X and summarize rest of the columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using following data set as an example:

```
       Age      Gender  CarType     Group   Education
1      46        Male      Sedan     1        BS
2      37        Male      SUV       1        MS
3      47      Female      Sedan     2        PhD
4      20        Male      SUV       2        HS
5      41        Male      SUV       1        MS 
6      52        Male      Sedan     2        MS
```

My goal is to group using the `Group` variable and then display stats for each column by group.

```
Group   Male  Female Female-Mean-age Male-Mean-AGE Sedan SUV PhD BS MS
 1       3      0         0               41.3      1     2    0  1  2
```

`df %>% group_by(Group) %>% summarise(n = n())` just give the counts but when I try to add mutate and collect counts for each gender I get error

`df %>% group_by(Group, Gender) %>% summarize(n=n()) %>% mutate(male = count('Male'))`

Do I need to include all the column in the `group_by` to have access later for sum or count or whats the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to `gather` into 'long' format and get the 'count' for the multiple columns, `spread` it to 'wide' format and then do a join with the `mean` of 'Age' calculated by 'Group' and 'Gender'

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
res1 <- gather(df1, key, val, Gender, CarType, Education) %>% 
               group_by(Group, key, val) %>% 
               summarise(n = n()) %>%
               ungroup %>% select(-key) %>% 
               spread(val, n, fill = 0)
res2 <- df1 %>% 
           group_by(Group, Gender) %>%
           summarise(Age_Mean = mean(Age))  %>% 
           mutate(Gender = paste0(Gender, "_Mean")) %>%
           spread(Gender, Age_Mean, fill = 0)
left_join(res1, res2)
# A tibble: 2 x 11
#  Group    BS Female    HS  Male    MS   PhD Sedan   SUV Female_Mean Male_Mean
#  <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     1  1.00   0     0     3.00  2.00  0     1.00  2.00         0        41.3
#2     2  0      1.00  1.00  2.00  1.00  1.00  2.00  1.00        47.0      36.0
```

Comment: getting `Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows` warning should i be gathering all columns or because warning comes even just with `gather`

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis  This solution is based on the example you provided there.  May be in the original dataset, there are duplicate rows, for which you need a group by sequence column.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative method that avoids `left_join` and intermediary objects, though it's your call whether you feel this is easier to understand or read. Without knowing the shape of the data it's hard to tell what will be easiest. This method needs just an extra line or two per extra different summary function you want to do, whereas the above needs another `left_join` and another `df` if you want the max age, say. However, if you have many more variables that all need counts, the above will be easier since it doesn't add lines for more variables with the same summary function.

The approach is basically to use `mutate` to add the right grouped summaries as new columns, and then use `spread` for each one to create the right column names. We can than reduce everything by `Group` with one call of `summarise`. I use `median` because it doesn't matter too much what summary function we pick, at this point all variables should have one value per group anyway and `mean` produces `NaN` which is a little irritating.

N.B. The last line with `mutate_at` turns all `NA` in the counts into 0. However, I chose not to replace the `NA` in the `mean_age_Female` , since `NA` there implies something different than a `0`. This is currently a difference in output between this solution and the other one, though it's a small fix.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- read_table2(
  "Age      Gender  CarType     Group   Education
  46        Male      Sedan     1        BS
  37        Male      SUV       1        MS
  47      Female      Sedan     2        PhD
  20        Male      SUV       2        HS
  41        Male      SUV       1        MS 
  52        Male      Sedan     2        MS"
)
#> Warning: 2 parsing failures.
#> row # A tibble: 2 x 5 col     row col       expected  actual        file         expected   <int> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>         <chr>        actual 1     5 <NA>      5 columns 6 columns     literal data file 2     6 Education ""        embedded null literal data

tbl %>%
  add_count(Group, Gender) %>% # Add all summary statistics as columns
  add_count(Group, CarType) %>%
  add_count(Group, Education) %>%
  group_by(Group, Gender) %>%
  mutate(., mAge = mean(Age)) %>%
  mutate(Gender2 = str_c("mean_age_", Gender)) %>%
  spread(Gender, n) %>% # Convert all to new columns
  spread(Gender2, mAge) %>%
  spread(CarType, nn) %>%
  spread(Education, nnn) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>% # Collapse to one row per group
  summarise_at(vars(-Age), function(x) median(x, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-starts_with("mean_age_")), function(x) replace_na(x, 0))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 11
#>   Group Female  Male mean_age_Female mean_age_Male Sedan   SUV    BS    HS
#>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  1.00   0     3.00            NA            41.3  1.00  2.00  1.00  0   
#> 2  2.00   1.00  2.00            47.0          36.0  2.00  1.00  0     1.00
#> # ... with 2 more variables: MS <dbl>, PhD <dbl>
```

Created on 2018-03-05 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).